# A brief explanation needed regarding newton's law in particle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

So based on the topic, this is the question.

"A particle with mass $m$ is moving along x-axis with $v_0$ at $t=0$ and $x=0$. The particle is acted by an opposing force with magnitude proportional to the square of velocity. Find out the a) velocity b) position and c) acceleration of particle at any time ($t>0$)"

I have the answers and solution for this but hardly understand them (I dont understand at all actually. Plus where does β come from?)

Basically I just need a clarification on question a) as b) and c) are related to the first question.

This is a self study for final exam. Answer provided by my friend but she also copied it from a source. So without understand it we do it correctly. But it seems to be useless. So I hope you guys can help me.

This is the answer.

a) velocity
[image: Part a]

b) position
[image: Part b]

c) acceleration (t>0)
[image: Part c]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the literal a), the problem say that the force is proportional to the square of velocity, i. e.

$F\propto v^2$

For that force is equal to the square of the velocity, you must put the constant of proportionality this is $\beta$, like the particle is acted by an opposing force then why the negative sign appears,

$F=-\beta v^2$

By Newton's second law $F=ma$ and $a=\dfrac{dv}{dt}$, then

$m\dfrac{dv}{dt}=-\beta v^2$

and only remains to integrate, as in the picture.

Hope that helps a little, if anything asks again :)

Comment: Thanks! You help me a lot and the explanation is crystal clear. Thank you very much :D :D